# Laravel Database Relation

Tags: laravel

Hey I want to make a relation between my posts table and my categorie table. But I can't get it working.

Here's my code:

```
Posts.php (model)

<?php
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = "posts";

    public function categorie()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo('Categorie');
    }
}
```

..

```
Categorie.php (model)

<?php
class Categorie extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = "categories";

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}
```

..

```
PageController.php (controller)

<?php
class PageController extends BaseController
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return View::make('layout.index')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
}
```

How can I show all my posts now with the categories they belong to?
I know if I do `$post = Post::find(1)->categorie` it returns the categorie that belongs to post id 1 but I want to return all my posts with the categorie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the relationship when you call in all the posts.

```
$posts = Post::with('categorie')->get();
```

Also, the method is `belongsTo` not `BelongsTo`.

Also, just a side note. The singular is category and the plural is categories. I'd have my model called `Category` and the relationship called `category`.